# How to resolve relative URLs on a website when looking for font files (chrome extension)

Tags: javascript, css, url, google-chrome-extension, relative-url

I'm working on a chrome extension that will allow me to download the font files from any website. I'm doing this by using chrome's [Web Request API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webRequest/) to grab all the stylesheets from a website and parse the `@font-face` declarations.

As I do this, I create a data structure that looks something like this:

```
Fira: [
  {
    URL: "/_next/static/media/FiraCode-VF.145e4ac7976fbd199e74c748a51585ee.woff2"
    format: woff2
    font-style: "normal"
    font-weight: "300"
  }
]
IBMPlexMono: (2) [{…}, {…}]
Inter: (2) [{…}, {…}]
```

The one thing I'm struggling with is resolving these relative URLs to their full URL. The example above, for instance, comes from https://tailwindcss.com. So I could easily prepend the root domain and resolve it to https://tailwindcss.com/_next/static/media/FiraCode-VF.145e4ac7976fbd199e74c748a51585ee.woff2. This will allow me to download the font.

However, on a site like https://creativemarket.com/ I'll get something that looks like this:

```
Averta: [
  {
    URL: “../fonts/averta-regular-webfont.woff2”
    format: woff2
    font-style: "normal"
    font-weight: "400"
  }
]
IBMPlexMono: (2) [{…}, {…}]
Inter: (2) [{…}, {…}]
```

That means I would have to get the URL from which the request was issued, and then traverse the path to resolve the URL.

So my specific question is as follows:

**Is there a way to tell whether I'm going to need to prepend the root domain or the requesting URL in order to get the full path?**

In other words, how would I have known on https://tailwindcss.com that the relative URL is **relative** to the root domain.

Comment: Your final question is a bit surprising... This case seems to be the simplest: `url.startsWith("/")`, the harder seems to be to find to what the partial URIs are relative to. But anyway it's unclear why you'd need to know either of these. URLs in a stylesheet are relative to the source of the stylesheet, so you can simply do `new URL(fontFaceDeclaration.URL, request.URL)` and you have your absolute URL.

Comment: @Kaiido Is it always the case that URLs in a stylesheet are relative to the source of the stylesheet? For example, here's the stylesheet from Tailwind that has the @font-face declarations: https://tailwindcss.com/_next/static/css/5a7d0dd00ff378096375.css

And the URL for the fonts looks like this: `"/_next/static/media/FiraCode-VF.145e4ac7976fbd199e74c748a51585ee.woff2"` 

So clearly the URL is not relative to the source of the stylesheet right? Seems to be relative to the root directory.

Comment: It is. And it is. `/` at the beginning of an URL means current domain + whatever comes after `/`. It is still relative to the stylesheet domain. For instance in your creativemarket.com example, such an URL would be relative to `https://d3ui957tjb5bqd.cloudfront.net` not to `https://creativemarker.com`.

Comment: Ahh yes, this works! Few things that were tripping me up:
1. I didn't know about the URL constructor
2. I was thinking of "./" and I didn't realize that "/" would always refer to the root directory.
Thanks a lot for the help!